# The general solution of $2x^2y''-xy'+y=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Find the general solution of $2x^2y''-xy'+y=x$.

My attempt:

Consider its homogeneous version: $2x^2y''-xy'+y=0$. Letting $y=x^r$ and substituting this and its first- and second- order derivatives in the equation, I have the characteristic equation $2r^2-3r+1=0$. This gives $r=1,\frac{1}{2}$. It follows that the complementary solution is

> $y_c(x)=C_1x+C_2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Now back to the original ODE. Dividing the whole equation by $2x^2$,

> $y''-\frac{1}{2x}y'+\frac{1}{2x^2}y=\frac{1}{2x}=g(x)$

Then consider the Wronskian

> $W= \begin{vmatrix} {y_1} & {y_2 }\\\ {y_1'} & {y_2'} \end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix} x & x^{\frac{1}{2}}\\\ 1 & (2x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-1} \end{vmatrix}=-\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$
>
> $W_1= \begin{vmatrix} 0 & y_2\\\ g(x) & y_2' \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 0 & x^\frac{1}{2}\\\ \frac{1}{2x} & (2x^\frac{1}{2})^{-1}\end{vmatrix}=(-2x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-1}$
>
> $u_1'=\frac{W_1}{W}=\frac{1}{x} \implies u_1=ln|x|+C$
>
> $W_2=\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 0\\\ y_1' & g(x)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} x & 0\\\ 1 & \frac{1}{2x}\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}$
>
> $u_2'=\frac{W_2}{W}=-x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \implies u_2=-2x^{\frac{1}{2}}+C$

So, we have the particular solution

> $y_p(x)=u_1y_1+u_2y_2=x\ln|x|-2x$

Hence, our solution is

> $y(x)=y_c(x)+y_p(x)=C_1x+C_2x^\frac{1}{2}+x(\ln|x|-2)$

I think I've solved the problem, but I'm currently reviewing this material for computational PDE course, so I'm not sure. Is something wrong with this?

Comment: The $-2$ doesn't actually matter because it can be absorbed into the arbitrary constant. But the solution looks good. You can verify it with the less computationally heavy method of undetermined coefficients. Since the inhomogeneous part is a homogeneous solution, multiply it by powers of $\log x$ until you have a linearly independent term. In this case we know that $$y_p = Ax\log x$$ and it is only a matter of solving for $A$ after plugging it in.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah you're right! And I realized that I completely forgot the undetermined coefficients method! I need to look it up later. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution involves $x^{1/2}$.  Does that mean there is no (real) solution for $x<0$?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks correct here is another approach:
$$2x^2y''-xy'+y=x$$
$$2y''-\dfrac {y'}{x}+\dfrac y{x^2}=\dfrac 1x$$
$$2y''-\left (\dfrac {y}{x}\right)'=\dfrac 1x$$
Integrate.
$$2y'-\dfrac {y}{x}=\ln x+ C$$
$$\left (\dfrac {2y}{\sqrt x}\right )'=\dfrac 1 {\sqrt x}(\ln x+ C)$$
$$\dfrac {2y}{\sqrt x} =2C \sqrt x +C_2+ \int \dfrac {\ln x} {\sqrt x}dx$$
$$y( x) =C_0  x +C_1\sqrt x+ x {\ln x} $$